# .htaccess File Testing

Tags: .htaccess, web, migration

While I was testing my .htaccess file I found that all the URLs redirection I added using **Redirect 301** code under RewriteEngine On are showing **This redirect was not followed.**

Is this correct or is there error in my .htaccess file?

Although it is showing valid

Comment: How should we say if what you added is correct if you keep secret _what_ you added and how you tested?

Comment: What does _"are showing This redirect was not followed"_ mean? Are you referring to some sort of external test tool's output here, or what exactly?